# How to write htaccess rewrite rule for redirecting pages which doesn't exist to 404 page

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

This is my htacces rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine ON

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

##Rules for existing php files rewrite.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^hosting/(.*)/?$ main-page.php?pagename=$1 [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ sub-page.php?pagename=$1 [NC,L]
```

If I enter a wrong url, for example:

'http://example.com/hosting/web-hosti' directs to 'http://example.com/main-page.php?pagename=web-hosti'  where 'web-hosti' page doesn't exist.

or

'http://example.com/contac' directs to 'http://example.com/sub-page.php?pagename=contac' where 'contac' page doesn't exist.

Can anyone please tell me how to redirect all wrong urls to 404 page?

Comment: You don't have to redirect them at all. You just set the `ErrorDocument`. If your logic (whatever logic you use) results in a status 404, then that document will get returned. You only need to rewrite (not redirect!) if your logic is incapable. Then you can define a final redirection as an exception for anything that has not been handled before in your configuration file.

Comment: @arkascha if i just set ErrorDocument 404 /404.php like this, its not working.. Can u please tell me what is wrong with my rewrite rule

Comment: You will need to remove the last two rule blocks as they override your `ErrorDocument` .

Comment: @AmitVerma I need those two blocks for my inner pages.. Is there any other way to make it work?

Comment: There is no way to make it work if you don't remove the last rule block. Your rule matches all 404 requests and rewrite those requests to `sub-page.php` . Your `ErrorDocument` isn't being read by server because it's part of a different module. `RewriteRule` directive is part of `mod-rewrite` and this directive always takes precedence over `ErrorDocument` and other directives.